# function that counts complete cases of id subset output order in R

Tags: r, subset

Creating a function that returns a list of User Id's and Number of observations per id that are complete cases.  Got the core code working but running into an issue where the return/output is organized in numerical ranking not how the argument is passed in to the function.  I've read what I can on stackoverflow and google looking at subsetting data and functions but can't isolate my problem of why the data is coming back ordered the way it is.

**Here's my code:**

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332){

    files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
    myfiles <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
    data.set <- subset(myfiles, ID %in% id)
    ans <- sapply(split(data.set, data.set$ID), function(y) sum(complete.cases(y)))
    ans
    return(data.frame(id = names(ans), nobs = unname(ans)))
}
```

And sample data being passed with output I'm getting:

```
complete("specdata", 30:25)
  id nobs
1 25  463
2 26  586
3 27  338
4 28  475
5 29  711
6 30  932
```

Comment: How is the initial input? I mean what do you expect  to happen? The list.files list the files in order of name, which may happen to be consecutive

Comment: What I expect to happen is if the function is passed complete("specdata", 30:25) the output table would start with id 30 nobs 932 and then do 29, 28 etc.  The list files section grabs the csv files from a folder and my understanding of the data.set subset is that it would grab them in the same order as id which in the case of this function call is 30:25.

Comment: The data file has 4 columns and thousands of rows.  Multiple rows with the same ID.  - is my subsetting call moving the organization into numerical order?

Comment: I won't check that now, I would need sample data so say it (and is late here), but why don't you sort it as you like after these function?

Comment: Your results are ordered according to the `ID` order in the file and not according to your `id` parameter, which is only used with the `%in%` operator.

Comment: Do a search on SO: `[r] complete 332`. I suspect you will find helpful material. (This is homework from Peng's class and students taking it are _supposed_ to post their questions on the help form for the course.) If you want to order a dataframe then use .... `order`